# querying many-to-many relationship on 3 table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 table

1. `Partcar`
2. `BarbellWheels`
3. `Assembly`

now, im confused how to manage this table to got connection, cause `Partcar` and `Assembly` is many-to-many relationship. But, `BarbellWheels` will merging with `Partcar` in `Assembly`. How to make this 3 table have many-to-many relationship, `Partcar` and `BarbellWheels` with `Assembly`.
And if it can, 3 table in 1, what a query to join them?

So far, what im thinking is, `BarbellWheels` join to `Partcar` 1st and then join to `Assembly`.

any advise?

EDIT :

There is 5 data on Partcar and must combine to 1 in Assembly and BarbellWheels will combine in Assembly with max 2 data on it.

EDIT EDITED : 
im just relize i didnt mention the relationship. here's the code.

```
CREATE TABLE `Partcar` (
     `partcarID` Char(7) NOT NULL,
     `partcar_price` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
     `partcar_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PartcarID`)
      );


ALTER TABLE `assembly` (
      `assemblyID` char(8) NOT NULL,
      `assembly_price` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `partcarIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `barbellIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`assemblyID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `partcar` (`partcarIDFK`),
      UNIQUE KEY `barbell` (`barbellIDFK`),
      CONSTRAINT `partcarIDFK` FOREIGN KEY (`partcarIDFK`) REFERENCES partcar(`partcarID`),
      CONSTRAINT barbellIDFK FOREIGN KEY (`barbellIDFK`) REFERENCES barbell(`barbellID`)
      );

ALTER TABLE `barbell` (
      `barbellID` char(10) NOT NULL,
      `name_barbell` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `carIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`barbellID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `car` (`carID`),
```

Comment: any advise? Yup - add table definitions, sample data and expected result as text to your question (or sqlfddle)

Comment: @P.Salmon im trying but, can you give me example? i cant submit a picture except give you a link picture, and im confused using sqlfddle, im still beginner about sql.

Comment: Am I missing something? Your diagram does not depict foreign keys relationships..  Are there any? If so can you edit your question?  If not, you should consider keying your data such that it will join nicely.

Comment: @terary im already join it, but in database looks like input the `ID`. 
then, im just using `SELECT` and `WHERE` with that `ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

Recipes

```
recipe_id recipe 
        1 cheese on toast
        2 macaroni and cheese
```

Ingredients

```
ingredient_id ingredient
          101 cheese
          102 toast
          103 macaroni
```

Recipe_Ingredient

```
recipe_id ingredient_id
        1 101
        1 102
        2 103
        2 104
```

Comment: but, i got 3 table. not 2.

Comment: So now you know what to do!

Comment: no, i meant, im still confused how to use detail table, and im googling it, why there are using left join instead inner or outer?

Answer (score -2):

Same cases in below url,Find the solution also.

> https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/383844/Sql-Queries-to-show-contents-of-the-table-many-to

Comment: Stack Overflow frowns on what they call "link only answers." I don't know for certain, but suspect that's why you've been downvoted. For more information about how to improve your answer, you can look at the discussion in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers